# "Oblong to Allantoid" — is it valid?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

I read in a [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3409409/):

> One such genus is *Dinemasporium* which ... characterised by superficial, cupulate to discoid conidiomata with brown setae, and phialidic conidiogenous cells that give rise to hyaline, oblong to allantoid, aseptate conidia with an appendage at each end.

In the phrase "oblong to *allantoid*", is the word *oblong* valid for this context? If not, what other word would work?

** I am editing to thank you all.  Although few people agreed to close this question (because they concern to the whole phrases), I should have told that I was confused for the phrase **oblong to allantoid**. It is clear now for me that oblong to allantoid means the range of *genus Dinemasporium* is **oblong (Roughly rectangular or ellipsoidal-shaped) to allantoid (Sausage-shaped; spores that are long with rounded ends).**
I also learned from [this journal](http://jcm.asm.org/content/36/9/2763.full) for the word oblong in the same context; *The conidia were subhyaline, oblong, and ellipsoid to allantoid.*

Comment: It looks to me like *oblong to Allantoids* is elliptical for *oblong cells that give rise to Allantoids*; but I'm totally baffled by the whole thing! Would this not be better suited to the [biology.se] site?

Comment: Ezekiel connected dem dry bones. Now hear the word of the Lord. Your toe bone connected to your foot bone. Your foot bone connected to your heel bone. Your heel bone connected to your ankle bone. Your ankle bone connected to your leg bone. Your leg bone connected to your knee bone. Your knee bone connected to your thigh bone. Your thigh bone connected to your hip bone. Your hip bone connected to your back bone. Your back bone connected to your shoulder bone. Your shoulder bone connected to your neck bone. Your neck bone connected to your head bone. Now hear the word of the Lord.

Comment: It is correct, but you have introduced some typos in your transcription. [See the sentence in this reference:](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3409409/) One such genus is Dinemasporium, which forms the basis of the present study. It is characterised by superficial, cupulate to discoid conidiomata with brown setae, and phialidic conidiogenous cells that give rise to hyaline, oblong to allantoid, aseptate conidia with an appendage at each end.

Comment: @JLG Yes, thanks. I have just found here too http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3409409/

Comment: Sounds like a quote from Blackadder.

Comment: GR. You are expected to be familiar with the usage of *oblong* **in the context**.

Comment: "Does it have _allantoid_?"

Comment: If you look up [allantoid](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/allantoid) it means sausage-shaped.  So *oblong* to *allantoid* means shaped like something somewhere between oblongs or sausages. Translated to something more closely resembling English (but completely ungrammatical), the phrase is *"glassy, oblong-to-sausage-shaped, not-having-septa conidia*.

Comment: Similarly, *cupulate* means *cup-shaped*, so *cupulate to discoid* means *shaped like cups or discs or something in-between*.

Comment: @PeterShor Oblong to Allantoid does make sense grammatically? I consider 'oblong' refers to a relativity of shape, not to position

Comment: The characterization parses like this: it has condiomata that are superficial and range from cupulate to discoid; it has brown setae; and it has phialidic conidiogenous cells that give rise to conidia that are hyaline and range from oblong to allantoid.  The part that you're having difficulty with is __The conidia range from oblong to allantoid__.

Comment: What type of sausage!?

Comment: Thank you all! I also learned from [this journal](http://jcm.asm.org/content/36/9/2763.full) for the word **oblong** in the same context; _The conidia were subhyaline, oblong, and ellipsoid to allantoid._.

Comment: @des The best thanks is to upvote and accept the answer which explained the range "oblong to allantoid".

Answer (score 1):

Certain kinds of English have particular rules that are not the same as conversation. For example recipes don't sound natural at all. In this case, the sentence is using a lot of highly specific words and eliding some. The two phrases X to Y refer to shapes that fit along a spectrum. The colour equivalent might be "red to orange" in one place and "yellow to green" in another.

To understand the sentence you need to understand each jargon word and possibly substitute the elided words. For example you might think "oblong to allantoid in shape" just as you might need to think "red to orange in colour". Same with earlier "cupulate to discoid in shape."

I might reword the sentence as:

> One such genus is Dinemasporium, which forms the basis of the present study. It is characterised by conidiomata that are superficial, and cupulate to discoid in shape, with brown setae. It is further characterized by phialidic conidiogenous cells. These conidigenous cells give rise to conidia. The conidia are hyaline, they are oblong to allantoid in shape, and they are aseptate. The conidia have an appendage at each end.

I'm still using their words but I've adjusted the structure to be less terse, a little more how you would explain this to another person. There's a lot of repetition in there, which is why textbooks tend to structure their sentences differently.

Comment: Oblong to Allantoid does make sense grammatically? I consider 'oblong' refers to a relativity of shape, not to position

Comment: That's the exact same comment you made above, and I can't understand it. Does "red to orange" make sense to you? Neither red nor orange refers to a position. How about "warm to hot" or "tired to exhausted"? You can take any two adjectives X and Y and describe a group of things as being "X to Y" meaning that some are X, some are Y, and some are in between. It's a terse wording, that might not be understood in conversation, but is understood in the context of describing a set of cells and how to know what they are.